# python numpy - convert Timestamps to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I have a np array such as follow:

```
example = np.array([[Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:00:00'), 1225.75, 1226.25, 1225.0, 1225.5,
        1668.0],
       [Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:30:00'), 1225.75, 1227.5, 1225.75, 1227.0,
        1603.0],
       [Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:00:00'), 1227.0, 1227.5, 1226.75, 1227.25,
        590.0]], dtype=object)
```

The first column is a Timestamp type value.
How do i convert those values to datetime?
I know there are few similar questions on the topic, but i couldnt manage to form a clear understanding of it and figure out a clean neat solution based on them.

I can convert the timestamp of a single value with `example[0,0].to_datetime()` but how to do it on all the Timestamps at once? ideally something like `example[:,0].`...

Comment: In your `example` `Timestamp` is not defined. Can you clarify?

Comment: I mean that I would like to convert the values such as  `Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:00:00')` to values such as `datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 17, 0)`.

Comment: I think what @JoeT.Boka asked is "where did you get the class `Timestamp` from?", correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This array is converted from a Pandas DataFrame. (`example = df.as_matrix()`). As far as iI understand it is not possible to convert a Pandas Timestamp to datetime within the DataFrame itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I define `Timestamp` as the `numpy` datetime dtype:

```
In [43]: Timestamp=np.datetime64
```

Then I can copy-n-paste your `example`:

```
In [44]: example = np.array([[Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:00:00'), 1225.75, 1226.25 , 1225.0, 1225.5, 1668.0],
    ...:        [Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:30:00'), 1225.75, 1227.5, 1225.75, 1227.0,         1603.0],
    ...:        [Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:00:00'), 1227.0, 1227.5, 1226.75, 1227.25, 590.0]], dtype=object)
```

Note that this array is `dtype` `object`

```
In [45]: example
Out[45]: 
array([[numpy.datetime64('2005-03-06T17:00:00'), 1225.75, 1226.25, 1225.0,1225.5, 1668.0],
       [numpy.datetime64('2005-03-06T17:30:00'), 1225.75, 1227.5, 1225.75, 1227.0, 1603.0],
       [numpy.datetime64('2005-03-06T18:00:00'), 1227.0, 1227.5, 1226.75, 1227.25, 590.0]], dtype=object)
```

The 1st column is:

```
In [46]: example[:,0]
Out[46]: 
array([numpy.datetime64('2005-03-06T17:00:00'),
       numpy.datetime64('2005-03-06T17:30:00'),
       numpy.datetime64('2005-03-06T18:00:00')], dtype=object)
```

which can be converted to an array of `datetime64` elements:

```
In [47]: example[:,0].astype(np.datetime64)
Out[47]: array(['2005-03-06T17:00:00', '2005-03-06T17:30:00', '2005-03-06T18:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

`tolist` for this type of array converts the elements to `datetime` objects:

```
In [48]: example[:,0].astype(np.datetime64).tolist()
Out[48]: 
[datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 17, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 18, 0)]
```

Alternatively, grabing the `pandas.Timestamp` function

```
In [50]: Timestamp = pd.Timestamp

In [52]: example
Out[52]: 
array([[Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:00:00'), 1225.75, 1226.25, 1225.0, 1225.5, 1668.0],
       [Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:30:00'), 1225.75, 1227.5, 1225.75, 1227.0,  1603.0],
       [Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:00:00'), 1227.0, 1227.5, 1226.75, 1227.25,  590.0]], dtype=object)

In [64]: ts = example[:,0]
In [65]: ts
Out[65]: 
array([Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:00:00'), Timestamp('2005-03-06 17:30:00'), Timestamp('2005-03-06 18:00:00')], dtype=object)
```

Iterative conversion of the Timestamp objects

```
In [67]: np.array([t.to_datetime() for t in ts])
Out[67]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 17, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 17, 30),
       datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 18, 0)], dtype=object)
```

But I discovered that `astype` works with `Timestamp` objects:

```
In [73]: ts = example[:,0]
In [74]: ts.astype('datetime64[s]')
Out[74]: array(['2005-03-06T17:00:00', '2005-03-06T17:30:00', '2005-03-06T18:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

So I can use that `tolist` to do the conversion in one line:

```
In [75]: ts.astype('datetime64[s]').tolist()
Out[75]: 
[datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 17, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 18, 0)]
```

I wouldn't describe this as a final solution, but it gives you an idea of how `numpy` deals with dates.

For array math I'd stick with the `datetime64` dtype.  To keep in one array along with the `example[:,1:]` floats you have to use a structured array.

=================

Experimenting with a copy:

```
In [80]: ex1 = example.copy()

In [82]: ex1[:,0] = example[:,0].astype('datetime64[s]').tolist()
In [83]: ex1
Out[83]: 
array([[datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 17, 0), 1225.75, 1226.25, 1225.0, 1225.5, 1668.0],
       [datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 17, 30), 1225.75, 1227.5, 1225.75, 1227.0, 1603.0],
       [datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 6, 18, 0), 1227.0, 1227.5, 1226.75, 1227.25, 590.0]], 
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: Hi thx, this is very useful and explanative. Would you have a tip so that the timestamps are converted to datetime *within* the original array? As per your example i'm left with an array containing only the timestamps. I know that what my suggestion but the final goal is of course to have that simple timeserie (i.e. the original "example") with its timestamps converted. The reason i have to do that is matplotlib plots.

Comment: Looks like I can just copy those `tolist()` results back into the original array.  Since `dtype` is object, it doesn't care that the elements change type.

Answer (score 2):

Helo, try:

```
example[:,0]= map(lambda x: x.to_datetime(), example[:,0])
```

Comment: I like this syntax as the `to_datetime` make it quite explicit what is going on. However when using your line, the following is contained in the variable example:`array([[<map object at 0x7ff675634940>, 1207.5, 1209.75, 1207.25, 1209.0,
        7659.0],` You can see there is a " `map object`" where there should be a `datetime.datetime`. Sorry I'm not familiar yet with Pandas etc. But am I missing something?

Comment: Oh I see are you using python 3? Try adding a list before map like: `list(map(...))`

Answer (score 0):

It's quite straightforward:

`t = np.datetime64('2018-08-18 23:25')` --> `numpy.datetime64('2018-06-18T23:31')`

`str(t)` --> `'2018-06-18T23:31'`

`t.tolist()` --> `datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 18, 23, 31)`

This will be all you need.

Comment: `Timestamp` is not always `np.datetime64`